# How to configure and ember-cli app instead of using command line options

Tags: ember-cli

I serve an ember-cli app using the following command

```
ember serve --proxy http://some.such.proxy --ssl --insecure-proxy
```

These options are specific to serving the app for development.  Can I configure my app, perhaps with `config/environment.js`, to use these options in development?

Ultimately I would just like to use `ember serve` without having to specify options on the command line.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Reading the documentation more carefully means that I can answer my own question.

[ember-cli environments](https://ember-cli.com/user-guide/#Environments)

Such options can be configured in the `.ember-cli` file